# firefox running slowly on redhat linux

Tags: firefox, performance, javascript, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have firefox version 3.6.13 and redhat linux and I've noticed firefox freezes up often, especially when opening new pages. I've seen some things citing javascript heavy sites as the cause of the problem but no other solution besides disabling javascript. Anyone know of any solutions that will allow me to keep both javascript and reasonable load times?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a real solution, but have you tried using [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling IPV6 support - worked for me with Fedora 14. This and more here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Error_loading_any_website